# jsRender , json column name with space

Tags: javascript, json, jsrender

How can I reference the column/field name with key name "Field ID" which includes space characters? Also "dtTime", shows as NaN.

```
<script id="jsRendTmp" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <li>{{:#Field ID}}</li>
    <li>{{:#dtTime}}</li>
```

**//Here's Proper way of doing it (thanx to Boris)**

```
<li>{{:#data['Field ID']}}</li>
<li>{{:#data['dtTime']}}</li>

</script>
```

Here's the data:

> testData: [
>           {
>               "Field ID": "22", 
>               dtTime: "8/1/2021"
>           },
>           {
>               "Field ID": "33", 
>               dtTime: "8/2/2021"
>           }
>       ]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the value like this:

`{{:#data['Field ID']}}`

If you want also to detect the key name and render it, take a look at this sample:
[03_iterating-through-fields-scenario](http://borismoore.github.com/jsrender/demos/scenarios/03_iterating-through-fields-scenario.html) - code [here](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender/blob/master/demos/scenarios/03_iterating-through-fields-scenario.html).

Comment: That's what i need !!! I was about to post on your Blog. Thank you Boris. And thank you again for a best rendering Lib !!!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a helper: http://jsfiddle.net/imsky/B8ks2/

```
<script id="jsRendTmp" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <div style="margin:10px 0">Title</div>
    {{for ~getFields()}}
    <li>{{>key}}: {{>value}}</li>
    {{/for}}
</script>
```

⁠

```
var data = [ { "Field ID": "22", dtTime: "8/1/2021" }, { "Field ID": "33", dtTime: "8/2/2021" } ];

    $.views.helpers({
        getFields: function( object) {
            var object = this.data;
            var key, value,
                fieldsArray = [];
            for ( key in object ) {
                if ( object.hasOwnProperty( key )) {
                    value = object[ key ];
                    // For each property/field add an object to the array, with key and value
                    fieldsArray.push({
                        key: key,
                        value: value
                    });
                }
            }
            // Return the array, to be rendered using {{for ~fields(object)}}
            return fieldsArray;
        }
    });

$("#content").html($("#jsRendTmp").render(data));
```

Comment: Looks good but a little overkill. I was looking for something simple :) I guess i'll just change back end to bring "valid" names.